# How to find the index based on the gathered population

Tags: r

A dataset has some patterns of gathered group. Here is the dataset:

```
index <- c(1:30)
a <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0)
b <- c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1)
c <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
d <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(cbind(index, a, b, c, d))
```

In general, the task is to identify the index (i.e., the column "index") when the data columns (i.e., a, b, c, d) show at least three consecutive value (i.e., 1) in its column and also its neighbor column show at least three consecutive value (i.e., 1).

For example, the result from the example below will output 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9. See highlighted consecutive value.

index   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

col-a 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1

col-b 1 0 1 0 1 1 **1 1 1**

col-c 0 **1 1 1** 0 0 **1 1 1**

col-d 1 **1 1 1** 0 0 0 0 0

The result should output the index: 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 27.

Comment: Good catch! I've corrected the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the most extensible solution, but it returns the desired result

```
# convert 1s that do not have at least runs of length 3 to 0
df[LETTERS[1:4]] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
                                     tmp <- rle(x)
                                     tmp$values[tmp$lengths < 3] <- 0L
                                     inverse.rle(tmp)})

# add neighbor columns use logical subsetting to return the relevant indices
df$index[(pmax(df[[LETTERS[1]]] + df[[LETTERS[2]]],
               df[[LETTERS[2]]] + df[[LETTERS[3]]],
               df[[LETTERS[3]]] + df[[LETTERS[4]]]) > 1)]
[1]  1  2  3  6  7  8 12 13 14 17 18 19 27
```

---

Here is a version that is extensible to n columns.

```
# convert 1s that do not have at least runs of length 3 to 0, put into list
l <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
                                 tmp <- rle(x)
                                 tmp$values[tmp$lengths < 3] <- 0L
                                 inverse.rle(tmp)})
```

Same as above, only store in a new object, for convenience. Now, use`Map` to return a list of the sums of adjacent columns. Use `do.call` with `pmax` to return the element-level maximum.

```
df$index[do.call(pmax, Map(function(x, y) l[[x]] + l[[y]],
                           head(seq_along(l), -1), tail(seq_along(l), -1))) > 1]
```

Comment: Good to know the R functions: rle() and pmax(). Would you mind if you add more description about why you used pmax()? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

```
sort(Reduce(union,
       lapply(lapply(2:(ncol(df) - 1), function(j) c(j, j + 1)), function(cols) {
           which(rowSums(sapply(df[cols], function(x)
             sapply(1:length(x), function(i) {
               sum(x[max(1, i - 1):min(i + 1, length(x))]) == 3 |
                 sum(x[max(1, i - 2):i]) == 3 |
                 sum(x[i:min(i + 2, length(x))]) == 3
             }))) > 1)
         })))
# [1]  1  2  3  6  7  8 12 13 14 17 18 19 27
```

Comment: Would you mind to add some description in the code or maybe break down the entire code ? Thx a lot.